# How to check how many times something occurs in a string in PHP

Tags: php, string

I want to check how many instances of the letter `a` appears in a certain string.

What is the function for this? I need it to return an integer value.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the function : [substr_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)

Example:

```
$str = "I love stackoverflow";
echo substr_count($str,'o'); // prints 3
```

Answer (score 5):

I suppose **[`substr_count`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)** could do the trick ;-)

For example, this portion of code :

```
$str = 'abcdazerty';
echo substr_count($str, 'a');
```

would get you the following output :

```
2
```

And, quoting :

```
int substr_count  (  string $haystack  ,  
    string $needle  [,  int $offset = 0  
    [,  int $length  ]] )
```

> `substr_count()` returns the number of
>   times the `needle` substring occurs in
>   the `haystack` string. Please note
>   that needle  is case sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

substr_count is probably the most straightforward. you can also do this

```
$str = "I love stackovaerflowa";
print count(explode("a",$str))-1;
```

Answer (score 1):

`substr_count($haystack, $needle);`

Answer (score -1):

you can refer to PHP string functions manual to find any function you need, http://php.net/strings