# How to count words delimited ',' in one string

Tags: php

I think it is php basic and simple question.

```
    $a = "";
    $b = "red";
    $c = "red,blue";

    echo(count(explode(',',$a))); 1
    echo(count(explode(',',$b))); 1
    echo(count(explode(',',$c))); 2
```

I would like to count how much string delimited ',' in one string

second and third line is OK,I think,however

I want first line returns 1;
is there any good way ?
thanks

Comment: Just check if it is empty. If so: zero;

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check how many times something occurs in a string in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497970/how-to-check-how-many-times-something-occurs-in-a-string-in-php)

Comment: $a is not empty its just the "". and this codes surely returns 1,1,2

Comment: echo substr_count($a,',');

Comment: @qwertynl thanks, but that article is different from my question..

Comment: since the only exception is "" why not check for that explicitly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`substr_count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) to count how many `,`'s there are in the string:

Example:

```
$a = "";
$b = "xs";
$c = "xs,oi";

echo(substr_count($a, ',')); // 0
echo(substr_count($b, ',')); // 0
echo(substr_count($c, ',')); // 1
```

---

To count the amount of words:

Example:

```
$a = "";
$b = "xs";
$c = "xs,oi";

$a_words = substr_count($a, ',') + (strlen($a) ? 1 : 0);
$b_words = substr_count($b, ',') + (strlen($b) ? 1 : 0);
$c_words = substr_count($c, ',') + (strlen($c) ? 1 : 0);

echo $a_words; // 0
echo $b_words; // 1
echo $c_words; // 2
```

We can also make a function to do what we want:

```
function count_words($string, $deliminator = ",") {
    return substr_count($string, $deliminator) + (strlen($string) ? 1 : 0);
}

echo count_words($a); // 0
echo count_words($b); // 1
echo count_words($c); // 2
```

Comment: I would like to count the words not ',' .

Comment: Hmmm ok. Ill update. Sorry I did not fully understand.

Comment: @whitebear I updated my answer to accomplish counting the number of words in the string deliminated by the comma

Comment: Thanks,this example slove my problems

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter).

```
$a = "";
$b = "red";
$c = "red,blue";

echo (count(array_filter(explode(',',$a), 'strlen'))); 
echo (count(array_filter(explode(',',$b), 'strlen'))); 
echo (count(array_filter(explode(',',$c), 'strlen')));
```